# ModuleNotFoundError in Python even though I have __init__.py in subdirectories

Tags: python, import, package, python-module, modulenotfounderror

My project is structured like this:

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eeYT.png)

The `_init_.py` files are empty. When I'm in the directory ats_program in the terminal and run `python lha/build_annoy_index.py` | get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named lha`. In `lha/build_annoy_index.py` it's this line of code that throws the error:

```
from lha.preprocessing. clean_text import clean_text
```

Why is this line of code not working? How can I import clean_text from la.preprocessing.clean_text? I want to just use the method containing `_init_ _. py` file instead of doing an import sys.

Comment: Does `from .preprocessing.clean_text import clean_text` work? As the `build_annoy_index` file is already in the `lha` module

Comment: You are trying to import `lha` from inside of `lha`. Just get rid of the `lha` reference.

Comment: Try running your code as a module: python -m lha/build_annoy_index.py

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy You were right. It worked!